# Super Admin not being enrolled in newly created program in valence desire 2 learn

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm working with the valence desire 2 learn api and making the call /d2l/api/lp/1.3/orgstructure/ to create a new program (and passing the proper object with it and I receive the proper object back). I am getting an object back and when I log into desire 2 learn the program has been created but I cannot access it. I am listed as not enrolled but I am the highest possible role (super admin cascading) so I should have access to everything. Any ideas why or how this can happen?

Comment: Can you let us know what the product component version is of the back-end service's LMS? I presume that this is a v10.2 Learning Environment? Do you know the service pack level applied to it?

Comment: 10.2.0 SP1 is what I'm using. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to reproduce this situation at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to confirm that this is a defect with the way the API operates to create custom org units. When the API creates a custom org unit, the user/roles that *should* be getting enrolled in the org unit via cascading enrollment are not being enrolled, whereas if you create the custom org unit through the Web UI, the cascading enrollment does take place.

I have logged this defect for you; the internal reference number is PRB0042167. Please have your approved support contact (or Account or Partner Manager) reach out to [Desire2Learn's Support Desk](http://helpdesk.desire2learn.com) if you would like to request status updates, and refer to this number.